# How to match latin and not latin characters by normalised version of string?

Tags: ruby, regex

How to find by `Bartlomiej Zolc` also string with latin version?
My current version matches only english version.

[regex101](https://regex101.com/r/tA0cX9/1)

```
/Bartlomiej Zolc/g

hello Bartłomiej Żółć match me!
hello Bartlomiej Zolc match me too!
```

Comment: Normalization is locale-dependent (i.e. the result of normalizing a particular character can vary depending on the language), so you should normalize your string according to the correct locale *before* testing it against your regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be prohibitively hard to normalize the thing you match against, so I recommend changing the regex.

I don't know if Ruby supports the `[=o=]` (which matches `o` and all its accented versions) POSIX [bracket expression syntax](http://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html), but there is also another way.

Replace every letter with an alternative accented form with a character class. For example:

```
/Bart[lł]omiej [ZŻ][oó][lł][cć]/g
```